# How to add a namespace and use it inside a XML document using SimpleXML (PHP)?

Tags: php, xml, namespaces, simplexml

I'm trying to add a new node inside a XML, with a namespace that is not defined, I tried to use SimpleXMLElement to add this namespace and create a node like:

```
<namespace:nodename>
```

but when I do, SimpleXMLElement gives something like this:

```
<nodename xmlns:namespace="namespace">
```

Here is the code that I've wrote:

```
$xml->addAttribute('xmlns:namespace', $url);
$xml->metadata->addChild('namespace:nodename', null, 'namespace');
```

And here's the XML that I'm trying to change:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<manifest xmlns="http://www.imsproject.org/xsd/imscp_rootv1p1p2" identifier="EXAMPLE_1" version="1.1">
    <someothernode>
    </someothernode>
    <metadata>
    </metadata>
</manifest>
```

Is SimpleXML the best way to add namespaces?

I've already tried another solutions found here in Stack Overflow, without success. I've even included a double namespace definition like "xmlns:xmlns:namespace" but it didn't also work.

The main problem is that the code that read this node that I'm creating fails when the node has additional attributes (uses xpath), it has to be clean like:

```
<namespace:nodename>
```

Answer (score 0):

Having namespace that is not defined, the document is not well-formed according to XML specification, hence isn't qualified to be XML. And commonly, XML parser designed to parse and produce only XML.

Possible approach maybe, if you really need to produce XML containing undefined namespace prefix, is to let simpleXML add new element with namespace declaration, and then do post-processing using something else (not an XML parser; maybe simple string operations or regex).

Alternatively, if you have control over the XPath, you might be able to make it works with any namespace by matching element using `local-name()` instead of the element qualified-name, f.e instead of `/nodename` you can do `/*[local-name()='nodename']`.